# IE only specific yet does not work in any other browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The items when put into the shopping cart allow you to remove each item  with the x in the top right corner. If you click that X in IE, the item is removed from the shopping cart, yet if you click it in any other browser, it does not remove the item?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/store/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/store/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>



<style type="text/css">

#background {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var total_items = 0;
    var total_price = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".item").draggable({
            revert: true            
        });
        $("#cart_items").draggable({
            axis: "x"
        });

        $("#cart_items").droppable({
            accept: ".item",
            activeClass: "drop-active",
            hoverClass: "drop-hover",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var item = ui.draggable.html();
                var itemid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                var html = '<div class="item icart">';
                html = html + '<div class="divrm">';
                html = html + '<a onclick="remove(this)" class="remove '+itemid+'">&times;</a>';
                html = html + '<div/>'+item+'</div>';
                $("#cart_items").append(html);

                // update total items
                total_items++;
                $("#citem").html(total_items);

                // update total price
                var price = parseInt(ui.draggable.find(".price").html().replace("$ ", ""));
                total_price = total_price + price;
                $("#cprice").html("$ " + total_price);

                // expand cart items
                if (total_items > 2) {
                    $("#cart_items").animate({width: "+=220"}, 'slow');
                }
            }
        });


        $("#btn_next").click(function() {
            $("#cart_items").animate({left: "-=200"}, 100);
            return false;
        });
        $("#btn_prev").click(function() {
            $("#cart_items").animate({left: "+=200"}, 100);
            return false;
        });
        $("#btn_clear").click(function() {
            $("#cart_items").fadeOut("2000", function() {
               $(this).html("").fadeIn("fast").css({left: 0});
            });

            $("#citem").html("0");
            $("#cprice").html("$ 0");
            total_items = 0;
            total_price = 0;
            return false;
        });
    });
    function remove(el) {
        $(el).hide();
        $(el).parent().parent().effect("highlight", {color: "#ff0000"}, 1000);
        $(el).parent().parent().fadeOut('1000');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).parent().parent().remove();
            // collapse cart items
            if (total_items > 3) {
                $("#cart_items").animate({width: "-=220"}, 'slow');
            }
        }, 1100);

        // update total item
        total_items--;
        $("#citem").html(total_items);

        // update total price
        var price = parseInt($(el).parent().parent().find(".price").html().replace("$ ", ""));
        total_price = total_price - price;
        $("#cprice").html("$ " + total_price);
    }
    </script>



        body {
            font-family: Arial, "Free Sans";
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #main {
            background: #0099cc;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #main a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        #main a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        #item_container {
            width: 200px;
            float:left;
            margin-left:10px;
            margin-top: -360px;
            height:400px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .item {
            background: #fff;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            cursor: move;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
            -moz-border-radius: .5em;
            border-radius: .5em;
            z-index: 5;
        }
        .title, .price {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: move;
        }
        .title {
            color: #333;
        }
        .price {
            color: #0099cc;
            margin-top: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
            -moz-border-radius: .5em;
            border-radius: .5em;
        }
        .icart, .icart label {
            cursor: e-resize;
        }
        .divrm {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .remove {
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            position: relative;
            top: -7px;
        }
        .remove:hover {
            color: #999;
        }
        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
        #cart_container {
            margin-top:0px;
            margin-left:260px;
            width: 565px;
        }
        #cart_title span {
            border: 8px solid #666;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
            background: #333;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
            border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        }
        #cart_toolbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 8px solid #666;
            height: 290px;
            z-index: -2;
            width: 565px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
            border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
            background: #ffffff;
        }
        #cart_items {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 0 0 2px;
            z-index: 0;
            cursor: e-resize;
            border-width: 0 2px;
        }
        .back {
            background: #e9e9e9;
        }
        #navigate {
            width: 545px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 8px solid #666;
            border-top-width: 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
            border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
            background: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #nav_left {
            float: left;
        }
        #nav_left a {
            padding: 4px 8px;
            background: #fff;
            -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
            -moz-border-radius: .5em;
            border-radius: .5em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color:#0099cc;
        }
        #nav_left a:hover {
            background: #666;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #nav_right {
            float: right;
        }
        .sptext {
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            margin-left: 8px;            
            -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
            -moz-border-radius: .5em;
            border-radius: .5em;
            color: #666;
        }
        .count {
            color: #0099cc;
        }
        .drop-active {
            background: #ffff99;
        }
        .drop-hover {
            background: #ffff66;
        }
```

Comment: where is your HTML code??

Comment: do you want items to be removable only in IE browsers?